# Facebook Tracking of In-Page Events with Conversion Pixel Code

Tags: facebook, events, onclick

Full disclosure - I'm not a programmer, but I'm the only one in my organisation who might be able to get this working. Can anyone help with the following please?

I'm trying to use Facebook's conversion pixel code to track certain button clicks on our site. Facebook's developer docs give the following instructions for tracking in-page events:

*After the base code snippet is installed, you can track in-page actions, such as clicks on a button, by making a _fbq.push('track') call for the conversion pixel through registering different event handlers on an HTML DOM element. For example:*

```
function trackConversionEvent(val, cny) {
  var cd = {};
  cd.value = val;
  cd.currency = cny;
  _fbq.push(['track', '<pixel_id>', cd]);
}
<button onClick="trackConversionEvent('10.00','USD');" /
```

The problem I'm facing is it's not clear to me what Facebook means by "the base code snippet". My initial assumption was that it's the conversion pixel code they give you to install in the head section of the page, i.e.

```
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code -->
<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', '<pixel_id>', {'value':'0.00','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=<pixel_id>&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

However, if I install the above on our page it loads/fires the conversion pixel code each time the page loads rather than on the button click (presumably because it's typically used on a thank you/confirmation page). Can anyone shed any light on this for me? I believe I understand where to position the onClick code to associate it with a button click but I'm struggling to understand where I need to position the trackConversionEvent code and what the base code snippet is. Through testing, I know that removing the following lines from the larger code snippet stops the pixel from loading:

```
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', '<pixel_id>', {'value':'0.00','currency':'USD'}]);
```

but I'm not sure if that's actually what I need to do. Do I for example, need to replace those two lines with the trackConversionEvent code so that the pixel doesn't fire when the page loads but the onClick code actually functions instead when the button is clicked?

Many thanks in advance for any pointers or suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, I.ve just tested on a blog based on WP.

```
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code -->
<script>(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
 })();
 window._fbq = window._fbq || [];

</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=<pixel_id>&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>     

<!-- End Of Facebook Conversion Code -->
```

This is the event handler that you could bind to any button, link or any DOM element::

```
function trackConversionEvent(val, cny) {
  var cd = {};
  cd.value = val;
  cd.currency = cny;
  _fbq.push(['track', '<pixel_id>', cd]);
}

<button onClick="trackConversionEvent('10.00','USD');"
```